# How are we supposed to get at matrix diagonals and partial regression plots using r programming?

Tags: r, statistics

Given the data

| farm | up | right | left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24.3 | 34.3 | 50 | 45 |
| 30.2 | 35.3 | 54 | 45 |
| 49 | 45 | 540 | 4353 |
| 70 | 60 | 334 | 343 |
| 69 | 80 | 54 | 342 |

```
    # for finding  Studentized residuals vs fitted value
    
    mod1<-lm(farm~up+right+left)
    plot(mod1)
    # for finding cooks distance
    
    plot(cookd(lm(farm~up+right+left, data=data)))
```

> could not find function "cookd"

I don't know how to find partial and diagonal matrix though I also couldn't find much information online.

Please help or correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Function `cookd` in in package `car`. So apparently all you have to do is to call `library(car)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas still not working also how to find matrix diagonals and partial regression plots?

Comment: Try `cooks.distance(mod1)` and `plot(cooks.distance(mod1))`.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *"matrix diagonals"*? What matrix? There are 6 regression plots, selectable by argument `which`, see `?plot.lm`. For instance, `plot(mod1, which = 2)` gives the normal Q-Q plot.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I am not quite sure if the matrix Diagonals vs observation number is the same with the QQ-plot. I doubt though! I couldn't find any information online as well. That's why makes me confused to understand!! Any ideas???